# Groupmembership powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to export Group membership - following is the script , however is it possible to 
put a filter based on User ID , like, I want to export all users, prefix with K

```
$FilePath = "c:/data/ADGroupmembership_09feb.csv"
$OuDomain = "DC=test, DC=abc, DC=com"
Get-QADUser -searchRoot $OuDomain -SizeLimit 0 | Select-Object dn, sAMAccountName, @{Name="Groups";Expression={(Get-QADMemberOf $_ | Select-Object -expandProperty Name) -join ";"}} | export-csv $FilePath | Sort-Object SamAccountName
```

==================================================

for example

```
samaccountname=*K*
```

or

```
$OuDomain = "CN=*K*,DC=test, DC=abc, DC=com"
```

Regards
Naveen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 Get-QADUser -SamAccountName k* -searchRoot $OuDomain -SizeLimit 0 | Select-Object dn, sAMAccountName, @{Name="Groups";Expression={(Get-QADMemberOf $_ | Select-Object -expandProperty Name) -join ";"}} | export-csv $FilePath | Sort-Object SamAccountName
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ... It's working fine. Could you please have a look on this link http://pastebin.com/9FPJrK3n I have some issue , I already asked this question. Thanks again for help.

Comment: For the other issue, if the problem is the memory, try to compare less user at a time filter as in this question like this: Get-Qaduser -samaccountname [a-e]* ... and after the other letters: [f-n]* and the [o-z]*